# Issues displaying date using datepicker

Tags: performance, date, datepicker

I am using the Datepicker jquery plugin to select the date. When I select the date using the Datepicker, it is displaying using the the format **"yy-mm-dd"**

However, when I donot select the date, the date is displayed in the **"dd/mm/yy"**

I tried to change the dateformat in jquery-ui.js from

> //dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", // See format options on parseDate
>
> dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", // See format options on parseDate

Any idea, how to change the dateformat for display as well ?

Comment: did you set date format in datepicker function?

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities:

1) Haven't initialized the dateFormat in your datepicker.  So try

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

2) Might be handled by other methods(not sure)